# List<List<string>> into ASP Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

I'm trying to input the data in my list of list of strings as rows in a ASP table element. All the correct data is passed through, but the rows repeat themselves by 3 times. How do add to the table element only once?

```cs
List<List<string>> table =  NorthwindAccess.GetProducts(ddl_Supplier.SelectedItem.Value);

for (int i = 0; i < table.Count(); ++i)
{
    for (int k = 1; k < table[i].Count(); ++k)
    {                    
        row1  = new TableRow(); //create as many rows as in each column (name, quantity, stock)

        for (int j = 0; j < table.Count(); ++j)
        {
            string cellData = table[j][k];
            TableCell cells = new TableCell();
            cells.Text = cellData;
            row1.Cells.Add(cells);                        
        }

        ProductsTable.Rows.Add(row1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the significance of each level of looping, to you? `i` loops over the rows, `k` loops over the columns, `j` does what?

Comment: @Ry without it each cell becomes a seperate row .

Comment: So create the row in the outer `i` loop, not the inner `k` one.

Comment: I created a helper method and got rid of j loop. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, ASP and ASP.NET are two different technologies.  ASP has been around since the mid-nineties. ASP.NET was named to build off ASP's popularity; as an "ASP for .NET", but they are very distinct